# How to use bash script with tmux terminal?

Tags: shell-script, tmux

I use tmux with shortcuts provided by the program.
How can i use my shell script for performing several options e.g:check if session exists etc.

Answer (score 0):

This shell script will tell if a session (provided by as the first argument) exists:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux has-session -t $1 2> /dev/null

# Check the return value of previous command:
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Session $1 exists"
else
    echo "Session $1 does not exist"
fi
```